# JSON.stringify() doesn't render the object that is changed by an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, object

Here is my code:

```
//column reorder event
dataTable.on('column-reorder', function (e, settings, details) {
    var userData = tableWidget.grid('userData');
    console.log(userData); //the object which is correct already
    console.log(JSON.stringify(userData)); //somehow it's different than without stringify
    $.ajax({
        url: "../../server/post.aspx?tableEvent=reordercolumns&table=SubContractor",
        data: { dataColumnOrder: userData },
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (response) {
            //write JS when ajax call success
            console.log('success');
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("Something wrong with the columns' reorder saving process");
        }
    });
    console.log("Reordered");
});
```

This event will update the `userData` object. the updating part works fine. Unfortunately, when I stringify it, the `userData` object comes back to the default value. Hereby I attached the screenshot of it:

Without Stringify `console.log(userData);`, (the correct one):

[image]

With Stringify `console.log(JSON.stringify(userData));`:

```
{
    "view": "SubContractorGridView",
    "title": "SubContractor Grid View",
    "settings": {
        "colOrder": ["Id", "ExtKey", "InsertionDate", "DeletionDate", "Name", "Address", "ZipCode", "EmailAddress", "PhoneNumber", "UserName", "Password", "LastUpdate", "Price"],
        "orderBy": "Name",
        "orderDir": "asc"
    },
    "columns": [{
            "dbField": "Id",
            "show": true,
            "widthMobile": 90,
            "widthPhablet": 89,
            "widthMiniTablet": 90,
            "widthTablet": 90,
            "widthSmallDesktop": 90,
            "widthDesktop": 90,
            "widthLargeDesktop": 90
        }, {
            "dbField": "ExtKey",
            "show": false,
            "widthMobile": 90,
            "widthPhablet": 120,
            "widthMiniTablet": 90,
            "widthTablet": 90,
            "widthSmallDesktop": 150,
            "widthDesktop": 90,
            "widthLargeDesktop": 100
        }, {
            "dbField": "InsertionDate",
            "show": true,
            "widthMobile": 90,
            "widthPhablet": 100,
            "widthMiniTablet": 90,
            "widthTablet": 90,
            "widthSmallDesktop": 100,
            "widthDesktop": 90,
            "widthLargeDesktop": 110
        }, {
            "dbField": "DeletionDate",
            "show": false,
            "widthMobile": 90,
            "widthPhablet": 90,
            "widthMiniTablet": 90,
            "widthTablet": 90,
            "widthSmallDesktop": 90,
            "widthDesktop": 90,
            "widthLargeDesktop": 100
        }, {
            "dbField": "Name",
            "show": true,
            "widthMobile": 90,
            "widthPhablet": 130,
            "widthMiniTablet": 90,
            "widthTablet": 90,
            "widthSmallDesktop": 90,
            "widthDesktop": 90,
            "widthLargeDesktop": 90
        }, {
            "dbField": "Address",
            "show": true,
            "widthMobile": 90,
            "widthPhablet": 90,
            "widthMiniTablet": 90,
            "widthTablet": 90,
            "widthSmallDesktop": 90,
            "widthDesktop": 90,
            "widthLargeDesktop": 90
        }, {
            "dbField": "ZipCode",
            "show": true,
            "widthMobile": 90,
            "widthPhablet": 90,
            "widthMiniTablet": 90,
            "widthTablet": 90,
            "widthSmallDesktop": 90,
            "widthDesktop": 90,
            "widthLargeDesktop": 90
        }, {
            "dbField": "EmailAddress",
            "show": true,
            "widthMobile": 90,
            "widthPhablet": 90,
            "widthMiniTablet": 90,
            "widthTablet": 90,
            "widthSmallDesktop": 90,
            "widthDesktop": 90,
            "widthLargeDesktop": 90
        }, {
            "dbField": "PhoneNumber",
            "show": true,
            "widthMobile": 90,
            "widthPhablet": 90,
            "widthMiniTablet": 90,
            "widthTablet": 90,
            "widthSmallDesktop": 90,
            "widthDesktop": 90,
            "widthLargeDesktop": 90
        }, {
            "dbField": "UserName",
            "show": true,
            "widthMobile": 90,
            "widthPhablet": 90,
            "widthMiniTablet": 90,
            "widthTablet": 90,
            "widthSmallDesktop": 90,
            "widthDesktop": 90,
            "widthLargeDesktop": 90
        }, {
            "dbField": "Password",
            "show": true,
            "widthMobile": 90,
            "widthPhablet": 90,
            "widthMiniTablet": 90,
            "widthTablet": 90,
            "widthSmallDesktop": 90,
            "widthDesktop": 90,
            "widthLargeDesktop": 90
        }, {
            "dbField": "LastUpdate",
            "show": true,
            "widthMobile": 90,
            "widthPhablet": 90,
            "widthMiniTablet": 90,
            "widthTablet": 90,
            "widthSmallDesktop": 90,
            "widthDesktop": 90,
            "widthLargeDesktop": 90
        }, {
            "dbField": "Price",
            "show": true,
            "widthMobile": 90,
            "widthPhablet": 90,
            "widthMiniTablet": 90,
            "widthTablet": 90,
            "widthSmallDesktop": 90,
            "widthDesktop": 90,
            "widthLargeDesktop": 90
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see the column's order somehow comes back to the default one with stringify.

Comment: There's not enough code here to find your bug or understand your goal.

Comment: What happens in the success callback?

Answer (score 0):

Strings are not dynamics, once you create the string and print it in console it won't change.
But objects are dynamics so when the object properties are changed you see the update values on console, because it concatenates the evaluation of the object.
You'll have to call `JSON.stringify` again if you want to display the updated value.
It is possible to clean the console if you are not interested in the older values with `console.clear()`
More about [console on chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-reference?)

Comment: you mean `console.clear()`  ... which is all well and good, but `Note that in Google Chrome, console.clear() has no effect if the user has selected "Preserve log upon navigation" in the settings.`

Comment: You can also hit `CTRL + L`. It's much more convenient than typing `console.clear()`

Comment: In my opinion Yusril Maulidan Raji would like to do it programatically

Comment: @Raulucco But, as you could see in my code, I put `console.log(JSON.stringify(userData));` right after `console.log(userData);`. Both of those should be the same. However, in my case, somehow those are different.

Comment: @YusrilMaulidanRaji as i said you have to call it again. Because before calling the ajax function the object has a different than in the success callback. You need to call it explicitly again to see the new state. This is because you made a function call and print a non dynamic value (string).

Comment: @Raulucco Oh, I see what you meant. For the updating object, it has no relation with the ajax. `column-reorder` is the one which updates the object. Afterward, I need to send the updated object to server via ajax.